# por que me sale que en el array el campo txt1 y txt4 no están definidos en el modelo?

Tags: php, html, mvc, actualizar

modelo

```php
<?php


    class producto{

        private $id;
        private $nombre;
        private $preciocompra;
        private $precioventa;
        private $descripcion;
        private $cantidad;
        


        public function registrar ($datos,$valor){

            
                include "conexion.php";

                $this->nombre=$datos['txt1'];
                $this->preciocompra=$datos['txt2'];
                $this->precioventa=$valor;
                $this->descripcion=$datos['txt5'];
                $this->cantidad=$datos['txt4'];

                $registrar=$conexion -> prepare ("call regproducto (?,?,?,?,?)");
                $registrar -> bindParam(1,$this->nombre);
                $registrar -> bindParam(2,$this->preciocompra);
                $registrar -> bindParam(3,$this->precioventa);
                $registrar -> bindParam(4 ,$this->descripcion);
                $registrar -> bindParam(5,$this->cantidad);

                $registrar -> execute();

                return 1;
            

            
        }

        
        public function consulta(){

            include "conexion.php";

            $consulta=$conexion ->prepare("call consultproducto");
            $consulta->execute();
            $tabla = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $tabla;
        }


        public function consultaespecifica($datos){

            include "conexion.php";

            $this->id=$datos["txt1"];
            $consulta=$conexion ->prepare ("call consultaesp (?)");
            $consulta ->bindParam (1,$this->id);
            $consulta->execute();
            $tabla = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $tabla;

        }

        public function actualizar($datos){

            include "conexion.php";

            $this->id=$datos['txt1'];
            $this->nombre=$datos['txt2'];
            $this->preciocompra=$datos['txt3'];
            $this->precioventa=$datos['txt4'];
            $this->cantidad=$datos['txt5'];
            $this->descripcion=$datos['txt6'];

            $actualizar=$conexion->prepare("call actuaproducto (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $actualizar->bindParam(1,$this->id);
            $actualizar->bindParam(2,$this->nombre);
            $actualizar->bindParam(3,$this->preciocompra);
            $actualizar->bindParam(4,$this->precioventa);
            $actualizar->bindParam(5,$this->cantidad);
            $actualizar->bindParam(6,$this->descripcion);


            $actualizar->execute();

            return 1;       

            

        }


        public function eliminar($datos){

            include "conexion.php";

            $this -> id=$datos["txt1"];
            $consulta=$conexion->prepare("call eliminarproducto (?)");

            $consulta->bindParam(1,$this->id);
            $consulta -> execute();

            return 1;
            
        }

    }

?>
```

controlador 4

```php
<?php

    include "../modelo/modelo.php";


    $instancia=new producto();
    $tabla=$instancia ->consultaespecifica($_GET);


?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head>
        <title>actualizar datos</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <section>
            <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                      Formulario 
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">

                        <form action="../controlador/controlador5.php" method="post" id="formulario1">


                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="floatingInput1"  required name="txt1" disabled value="<?php echo $tabla["0"]["id"];?>">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput1"  required name="txt2"  value="<?php echo $tabla["0"]["nombre"];?>">
                                <label for="floatingInput1">Nombre</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="floatingInput2"  required name="txt3" value="<?php echo $tabla["0"]["preciocompra"];?>"  >
                              <label for="floatingInput2">Precio compra</label>
            
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="floatingInput2"  required name="txt4" disabled value="<?php echo $tabla["0"]["precioventa"];?>"  >
                              <label for="floatingInput2">Precio venta</label>
            
                            </div>
                          
                          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="floatingInput3"  required name="txt5" value="<?php echo $tabla["0"]["cantidad"];?>" >
                            <label for="floatingInput3">Cantidad</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput3"  required name="txt6" value="<?php echo $tabla["0"]["descripcion"];?>">
                            <label for="floatingInput3">Descripcion</label>
                          </div>
                        
                           <br>
                            <div class="form-floating">
                                <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button></center>
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>

</html>
```

controlador 5

```php
<?php

    include "../modelo/modelo.php";
    $instancia = new producto();
    $respuesta = $instancia->actualizar($_POST);

    if($respuesta===1){
        echo "<script>
        
        </script> "
        ;
    }

    else {

        echo "<script>alert('Registro fallido');
        location.href='controlador4.php';
        </script>";
    }

         var_dump ($_POST);


?>
```

Comment: Buenas, Nicole, bienvenida al sitio. No hace falta que pongas todo el código, incluye solo la parte relevante e indica en qué línea te está saliendo ese error. y describe someramente qué querías hacer. Aunque ya te digo una cosa, controlador4 no está recibiendo nada en $_GET, al menos que se aprecie en lo que pones. No hay parámetros en el href, si es que ese trozo llega a hacer la redirección